# Passbook using passkit - pass no longer valid

Tags: php, passbook, passkit

I have a php project that creates passbook files using passkit. It was working fine since last spring but today we noticed that when you open the passbook on mac it says "this pass is no longer valid" and of course I can't download it using the passbook's QR scan as it used to work. Any suggestions? My passbook certificates expire in one month and my ssl certificates expire in 3 months...

EDIT---------

I created new pass type identifier, new certificate and new apple root certificate. Now on my mac it appears fine but the iphone can't add the passbook. The error now is:

"The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple asked all Apple developer to update WWDRCA file unless your system will  work only up to Feb 14, 2016. Have you update it?